# socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed,django

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-requests, betfair

I am trying create a Betfair interactive login following this [tutorial ][1]
and i keep on getting and error my app_key is correct and my username and password also correct but i think i am not getting hoe to set it to work correctly please any help will be grateful here is my code

```
import requests
import json

login_hearders = {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'X-Application':APP_KEY_HERE,
        'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded '}

url = 'https://identitysso.betfair.au/api/login'

payload = {'username':'USERNAME_HERE','password':'PASSWORD_HERE'}


r = requests.post(url, data=payload,headers=login_hearders)

print(json.loads(r.text))
```

Comment: Please don't be too lazy to find existing answers before asking such a simple question. Googling for "socket error: [Errno 11004]" gives you plenty of hints (BTW: Socket-Errors - recognizable due its number range 10000<errorno - come from the OS and not from django, python or what else programming language.)

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what tutorial you were trying to follow, however, that particular host (`identitysso.betfair.au`) is wrong. You want the **`com`**`.au` version.

```
me@host$ host identitysso.betfair.au
Host identitysso.betfair.au not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

me@host$ host identitysso.betfair.com.au
identitysso.betfair.com.au has address 987.654.32.1
```

(not showing actual DNS resolution, since that's the point of DNS)